# How to share (config.vm.synced_folder), directories between Windows 10 and CentOS7 Virtual Machine created using Vagrant and VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7, shared-directory

I'm trying to create a VM CentOS7 using Vagrant (2.2.3) and Virtual Box (6.0.4), on Windows 10 using the following Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7" 
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.3"

  config.vm.synced_folder "D://SharedWithVM//CentOS7-Work", "/media/sf_CentOS7-Work", type: "virtualbox"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "Test"
   end
   config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/InstallGuestAdditions.sh"
end
```

and the `InstallGuestAdditions.sh` shell script is the follow ..

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -C - -O http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
sudo mkdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo mount -o loop,ro VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo sh /media/VBoxGuestAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
rm VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
sudo umount /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo rmdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

All works fine and the CentOS7 VM is created.

If I check the machine properties about shared directories I can see this

[image]

So I'm quite surprised  about this path `\\?\D:\SharedWithVM\CentOS7-Work`.

How should I change my  Vagrantfile to obtain a right path?

I've tried to connect at my CentOS 7 VM using `vagrant ssh` command and all works. Also the command `cd /media/sf_CentOS7-Work` works fine but no file or directory can be listed or shared between the two systems.

I've tried to create files or directories in Windows 10 and also in CentOS7 VM.

Any suggestion or example will be appreciated.

Comment: I think your slashes are wrong: "D:/SharedWithVM/CentOS7-Work" or "D:\\SharedWithVM\\CentOS7-Work" but not double //.